# Java creating a new frame

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jframe

```
public static void main(String[] arguments){
    TicTac frame = new TicTac();
}
```

The second TicTac says cannot find symbol and asks to create constructor `TicTac();`.

My constructer is as follows:

```
public TicTac(TicTac in) {

}
```

I have tried

```
TicTac frame = new TicTac(TicTac in);
```

Here is the whole code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import tictactoe.TicTac;


public class TicTac extends JFrame implements ItemListener, ActionListener, Runnable{
    TicTac gui;
    Thread playing;
    TicTacEvent tictac = new TicTacEvent(this);
    JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
    JButton[][] boxes = new JButton[3][3];
    JButton play = new JButton("Play");
    JTextField blank1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField blank2 = new JTextField();
    JOptionPane win = new JOptionPane("Winner");
    ImageIcon back = new ImageIcon("cardback.jpg");
    ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("x.jpg");
    ImageIcon b = new ImageIcon("o.jpg");
    int clicks = 0;
    //int win = 0;
    int winX = 0;
    int winO = 0;
    int tie = 0;
    int[][] check = new int[3][3];

    public TicTac(TicTac in) {
        super ("Tic Tac Toe");
        gui = in;
        setSize (500,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(layout);
        int name = 0;
        String newname;

        for (int row=0; row<=2;row++){
            for(int col=0; col<=2; col++){
                check[row][col]=0;
            }
        }

        GridLayout layout1 = new GridLayout(4, 3, 10, 10);
        row1.setLayout(layout1);
        for (int x=0; x<=2; x++){
            for (int y=0; y<=2; y++){
                name = name + 1;
                newname = Integer.toString(name);
                boxes[x][y] = new JButton(newname);
                boxes[x][y].setIcon(back);
                row1.add(boxes[x][y]);
            }
        }
        row1.add(blank1);
        row1.add(play);
        row1.add(blank2);
        add (row1);

        play.addActionListener(tictac);
        for (int x=0; x<=2; x++){
            for (int y=0; y<=2; y++){
                boxes[x][y].addActionListener(tictac);
            }
        }


        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        TicTac frame = new TicTac();
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
       String command = event.getActionCommand();

       if (command.equals("Play")) {
           startPlaying();
       }
       if (command.equals("1")) {
           b1();
       }
       if (command.equals("2")) {
           b2();
       }
       if (command.equals("3")) {
           b3();
       }
       if (command.equals("4")) {
           b4();
       }
       if (command.equals("5")) {
           b5();
       }
       if (command.equals("6")) {
           b6();
       }
       if (command.equals("7")) {
           b7();
       }
       if (command.equals("8")) {
           b8();
       }
       if (command.equals("9")) {
           b9();
       }
    }

    void b1() {
        clicks = clicks + 1;
        if ((clicks%2)==1){
            gui.boxes[0][0].setIcon(a);
            check[0][0] = 1;
        } else {
            gui.boxes[0][0].setIcon(b);
            check[0][0] = 2;
        }
        winner();

    }
    void b2() {
        clicks = clicks + 1;
        if ((clicks%2)==1){
            gui.boxes[0][1].setIcon(a);
            check[0][1] = 1;
        } else {
            gui.boxes[0][1].setIcon(b);
            check[0][1] = 2;
        }
        winner();
    }
    void b3() {
        clicks = clicks + 1;
        if ((clicks%2)==1){
            gui.boxes[0][2].setIcon(a);
            check[0][2] = 1;
        } else {
            gui.boxes[0][2].setIcon(b);
            check[0][2] = 2;
        }
        winner();
    }
    void b4() {
        clicks = clicks + 1;
        if ((clicks%2)==1){
            gui.boxes[1][0].setIcon(a);
            check[1][0] = 1;
        } else {
            gui.boxes[1][0].setIcon(b);
            check[1][0] = 2;
        }
        winner();
    }
    void b5() {
        clicks = clicks + 1;
        if ((clicks%2)==1){
            gui.boxes[1][1].setIcon(a);
            check[1][1] = 1;
        } else {
            gui.boxes[1][1].setIcon(b);
            check[1][1] = 2;
        }
        winner();
    }
    void b6() {
        clicks = clicks + 1;
        if ((clicks%2)==1){
            gui.boxes[1][2].setIcon(a);
            check[1][2] = 1;
        } else {
            gui.boxes[1][2].setIcon(b);
            check[1][2] = 2;
        }
        winner();
    }
    void b7() {
        clicks = clicks + 1;
        if ((clicks%2)==1){
            gui.boxes[2][0].setIcon(a);
            check[2][0] = 1;
        } else {
            gui.boxes[2][0].setIcon(b);
            check[2][0] = 2;
        }
        winner();
    }
    void b8() {
        clicks = clicks + 1;
        if ((clicks%2)==1){
            gui.boxes[2][1].setIcon(a);
            check[2][1] = 1;
        } else {
            gui.boxes[2][1].setIcon(b);
            check[2][1] = 2;
        }
        winner();
    }
    void b9() {
        clicks = clicks + 1;
        if ((clicks%2)==1){
            gui.boxes[2][2].setIcon(a);
            check[2][2] = 1;
        } else {
            gui.boxes[2][2].setIcon(b);
            check[2][2] = 2;
        }
        winner();
    }

    void winner() {
        /** Check rows for winner */

        for (int x=0; x<=2; x++){
            if ((check[x][0]==check[x][1])&&(check[x][0]==check[x][2])) {
                if (check[x][0]==1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X is the winner");
                    winX = 1;
                    System.out.println(Integer.toString(winX));
                    blank1.setText("Number of X Wins = " + (Integer.toString(winX)));
                } else if (check[x][0]==2){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O is the winner");
                    winO = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        /** Check columns for winner */
        for (int x=0; x<=2; x++){
            if ((check[0][x]==check[1][x])&&(check[0][x]==check[2][x])) {
                if (check[0][x]==1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X is the winner");
                    winX = 1;
                } else if (check[0][x]==2) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O is the winner");
                    winO = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        /** Check diagonals for winner */
        if (((check[0][0]==check[1][1])&&(check[0][0]==check[2][2]))||
                ((check[2][0]==check[1][1])&&(check[1][1]==check[0][2]))){
            if (check[1][1]==1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X is the winner");
                winX = 1;
            } else if (check[1][1]==2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O is the winner");
                winO = 1;
            }

        }

        /** Checks if the game is a tie */
       /* if ((clicks==9) && (win==0)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The game is a tie");
        }
    */}


    void startPlaying() {
        playing = new Thread(this);
        playing.start();
        gui.play.setEnabled(false);
    }


    public void run() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

To fix my problem I created a separate class.
Class one:

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

public class TicTac extends JFrame { 
 TicTacEvent tictac = new TicTacEvent(this); 

 JPanel row1 = new JPanel(); 
 JButton[][] boxes = new JButton[3][3]; 
 JButton play = new JButton("Play"); 
 JTextField blank1 = new JTextField(); 
 JTextField blank2 = new JTextField(); 
 JOptionPane win = new JOptionPane("Winner"); 
 ImageIcon back = new ImageIcon("cardback.jpg"); 


 public TicTac() { 
 super ("Tic Tac Toe"); 
 setSize (500,600); 
 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
 FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout(); 
 setLayout(layout); 
 int name = 0; 
 String newname; 

 GridLayout layout1 = new GridLayout(4, 3, 10, 10); 
 row1.setLayout(layout1); 
 for (int x=0; x<=2; x++){ 
 for (int y=0; y<=2; y++){ 
 name = name + 1; 
 newname = Integer.toString(name); 
 boxes[x][y] = new JButton(newname); 
 boxes[x][y].setIcon(back); 
 row1.add(boxes[x][y]); 
 } 
 } 
 row1.add(blank1); 
 row1.add(play); 
 row1.add(blank2); 
 add (row1); 

 play.addActionListener(tictac); 
 for (int x=0; x<=2; x++){ 
 for (int y=0; y<=2; y++){ 
 boxes[x][y].addActionListener(tictac); 
 } 
 }  

 setVisible(true); 
 } 

 public static void main(String[] arguments){ 
 TicTac frame = new TicTac(); 
 } 
}
```

Class 2:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.awt.*; 

public class TicTacEvent implements ItemListener, ActionListener, Runnable { 
 TicTac gui; 
 Thread playing; 
 ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("x.jpg"); 
 ImageIcon b = new ImageIcon("o.jpg"); 
 int clicks = 0; 
 int win = 0; 
 int[][] check = new int[3][3]; 

 public TicTacEvent (TicTac in){ 
 gui = in; 
 for (int row=0; row<=2; row++){ 
 for (int col=0; col<=2; col++){ 
 check[row][col]=0; 
 } 
 } 
 } 

 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) { 
 String command = event.getActionCommand(); 

 if (command.equals("Play")) { 
 startPlaying(); 
 } 
 if (command.equals("1")) { 
 b1(); 
 } 
 if (command.equals("2")) { 
 b2(); 
 } 
 if (command.equals("3")) { 
 b3(); 
 } 
 if (command.equals("4")) { 
 b4(); 
 }  if (command.equals("5")) { 
 b5(); 
 } 
 if (command.equals("6")) { 
 b6(); 
 } 
 if (command.equals("7")) { 
 b7(); 
 } 
 if (command.equals("8")) { 
 b8(); 
 } 
 if (command.equals("9")) { 
 b9(); 
 } 
 } 

 void b1() { 
 clicks = clicks + 1; 
 if ((clicks%2)==1){ 
 gui.boxes[0][0].setIcon(a); 
 check[0][0] = 1; 
 } else { 
 gui.boxes[0][0].setIcon(b); 
 check[0][0] = 2; 
 } 
 winner(); 

 } 
 void b2() { 
 clicks = clicks + 1; 
 if ((clicks%2)==1){ 
 gui.boxes[0][1].setIcon(a); 
 check[0][1] = 1; 
 } else { 
 gui.boxes[0][1].setIcon(b); 
 check[0][1] = 2; 
 } 
 winner(); 
 } 
 void b3() { 
 clicks = clicks + 1; 
 if ((clicks%2)==1){ 
 gui.boxes[0][2].setIcon(a); 
 check[0][2] = 1; 
 } else {  gui.boxes[0][2].setIcon(b); 
 check[0][2] = 2; 
 } 
 winner(); 
 } 
 void b4() { 
 clicks = clicks + 1; 
 if ((clicks%2)==1){ 
 gui.boxes[1][0].setIcon(a); 
 check[1][0] = 1; 
 } else { 
 gui.boxes[1][0].setIcon(b); 
 check[1][0] = 2; 
 } 
 winner(); 
 } 
 void b5() { 
 clicks = clicks + 1; 
 if ((clicks%2)==1){ 
 gui.boxes[1][1].setIcon(a); 
 check[1][1] = 1; 
 } else { 
 gui.boxes[1][1].setIcon(b); 
 check[1][1] = 2; 
 } 
 winner(); 
 } 
 void b6() { 
 clicks = clicks + 1; 
 if ((clicks%2)==1){ 
 gui.boxes[1][2].setIcon(a); 
 check[1][2] = 1; 
 } else { 
 gui.boxes[1][2].setIcon(b); 
 check[1][2] = 2; 
 } 
 winner(); 
 } 
 void b7() { 
 clicks = clicks + 1; 
 if ((clicks%2)==1){ 
 gui.boxes[2][0].setIcon(a); 
 check[2][0] = 1; 
 } else { 
 gui.boxes[2][0].setIcon(b); 
 check[2][0] = 2;  } 
 winner(); 
 } 
 void b8() { 
 clicks = clicks + 1; 
 if ((clicks%2)==1){ 
 gui.boxes[2][1].setIcon(a); 
 check[2][1] = 1; 
 } else { 
 gui.boxes[2][1].setIcon(b); 
 check[2][1] = 2; 
 } 
 winner(); 
 } 
 void b9() { 
 clicks = clicks + 1; 
 if ((clicks%2)==1){ 
 gui.boxes[2][2].setIcon(a); 
 check[2][2] = 1; 
 } else { 
 gui.boxes[2][2].setIcon(b); 
 check[2][2] = 2; 
 } 
 winner(); 
 } 

 void winner() { 
 /** Check rows for winner */ 

 for (int x=0; x<=2; x++){ 
 if ((check[x][0]==check[x][1])&&(check[x][0]==check[x][2])) { 
 if (check[x][0]==1) { 
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X is the winner"); 
 win = 1; 
 } else if (check[x][0]==2){ 
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Y is the winner"); 
 win = 1; 
 } 
 } 
 } 

 /** Check columns for winner */ 
 for (int x=0; x<=2; x++){ 
 if ((check[0][x]==check[1][x])&&(check[0][x]==check[2][x])) { 
 if (check[0][x]==1) { 
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X is the winner");  win = 1; 
 } else if (check[0][x]==2) { 
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Y is the winner"); 
 win = 1; 
 } 
 } 
 } 

 /** Check diagonals for winner */ 
 if (((check[0][0]==check[1][1])&&(check[0][0]==check[2][2]))|| 
 ((check[2][0]==check[1][1])&&(check[1][1]==check[0][2]))){ 
 if (check[1][1]==1) { 
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X is the winner"); 
 win = 1; 
 } else if (check[1][1]==2) { 
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Y is the winner"); 
 win = 1; 
 } 

 } 

 /** Checks if the game is a tie */ 
 if ((clicks==9) && (win==0)) { 
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The game is a tie"); 
 } 
 } 


 void startPlaying() { 
 playing = new Thread(this); 
 playing.start(); 
 gui.play.setEnabled(false); 
 } 

 public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) { 
 throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
 } 

 public void run() { 
 throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
 } 


}
```

Comment: How can you pass a reference of an object which you can't create, because you need to pass a reference of instance to it....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor requires you to pass in an existing `TicTac` as a parameter. In the code you show, you're trying to create a `TicTac` without doing so.

As @MadProgrammer points out, requiring a `TicTac` to create a `TicTac` creates something of a catch-22 situation: How can you ever create one without having one first? If, for some reason, you do need to create a `TicTac` with a reference to an existing `TicTac`, you need to create an additional constructor with no parameters (as your compiler is suggesting) to create the first one:

```
 public TicTac() {  }
```

(more accurately, your constructor can take parameters, it just cant require a `TicTac`):

```
class TicTac { 
    public TicTac(int size) { }
    public TicTac(TicTac otherTicTac) { }
    ...
 }
 //elsewhere: 
 TicTac first = new TicTac(5);  //or just TicTac first = new TicTac() 
 TicTac second = new TicTac(first);
```

However, I'm guessing that you don't really need a `TicTac(TicTac otherTicTac)` constructor (if so, tell me why), and that you're trying to do so as a result of a misunderstanding about how constructors work - in which case [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) might be a helpful read, for starters.

Comment: I have tried `TicTac frame = new TicTac(TicTac in);` but that doesnt work

Comment: Look more closely at my answer. `new TicTac(TicTac in)` does not make sense, and will not compile. `TicTac(TicTac in)` would be a *constructor*, not an invocation.

Comment: @ConorWatt Why do you need `in`?  What's it's purpose?

Comment: So if my constructer is called TicTac(TicTac in) how would I use that to compile the game?

Comment: @MadProgrammer its setting the gui

Comment: @ConorWatt You already *have* that constructor - and we're talking about why you *can't* use it to compile the game (at least without having another constructor, which I doubt you need). If by "setting the gui" you mean assigning your `TicTac` to a Swing container, use `public TicTac(JPanel panel)` (or whatever container you're using) as your constructor instead.

Comment: @drewmore `public static void main(String[] arguments){`
            `TicTac frame = new ???;`
            `}`

Comment: @ConorWatt `= new TicTac()` , after first changing your `TicTac` ***constructor*** from `public TicTac(TicTac in)` to `public TicTac()`. Note that I am only suggesting a quick fix to get your program working. You should really put some thought into the difference between those constructors, and do some reading about what constructors *are*, what they *do*, and what *parameters* into them are used for.

Comment: @ConorWatt: they're telling you to ***change*** the constructor. You have never justified anywhere the need for the parameter because you can't. Get rid of the stupid parameter that serves no purpose other than to fark up your code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I changed the constructor and I am still getting the same error as I was in the first place

Comment: @ConorWatt Why do you need to pass an instance of `TicTac` to `TicTac`?  It doens't make sense

Comment: @MadProgrammer What do you mean?

Comment: @ConorWatt I think the crux of the issue here is that you're not understanding the question that MadProgrammer asked in the question above, which is the same question implied by HovercraftFullOfEels above, and the same question I asked in my original answer. If you want to make some progress in wrapping your head around Java (and OOP in general) here, put some hard thought into what that question is asking. I bet you'll end up answering your own question.

Comment: @ConorWatt You have a chicken and egg problem.  In order to create an instance of `TicTac`, you must pass it an instance of `TicTac`, but you can't create an instance of `TicTac` because you need an instance of `TicTac` to start with...

Comment: @drewmore I did answer my own question, thanks. I missed your previous response.

Comment: @ConorWatt: where did you answer your own question? Are you clear on the issue now? Do you understand what we've been driving at?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I fully understand now

Comment: @ConorWatt for reference (and so we can make sure you've got it), why don't you edit your question with the explanation that made it click for you - to help people in your position in the future.